# Show footer fixed at bottom right, Deafult is left (CSS/HTML5)

Tags: html, css

I am Trying to Place My Footer in the bottom Right of the page. I am using the HTML5's `<footer>` tags.

So, here is what i have in my CSS:

```
footer {
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    float: right;
    height: 35px;
    margin: 0px 50px 0px 0px;
    background: #9FF;
    color: #000;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 10px 30px;
}
```

With this code the footer perfectly sticks to the bottom. What i want is that it should also  be in the rightmost part of the footer as well.

http://i47.tinypic.com/2rrox0w.png

So, when i use the following code: `right: 50px` in the CSS. Then the footer gets positioned relative to the browser. So, whenever i Resize my browser the footer is dislocated.

**What i Want ?**

I want to footer to be placed at the bottom. And at a a margin of 50px(right) from the **container**(#main or #maincontent) it is placed in rather than the browser. The `float: right` does not seem to work.

I have looked the whole internet and stackoverflow as well. But, could not find a solution to this kind of issue.

I am using Google Chrome 22. So, My Browser is largely HTML5 compatible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated: you don't need to position it absolute, just remove the position, give some width to your footer and float it towards right like this

```
footer {
    float: right;
    height: 35px;
    margin: 0px 50px 0px 0px;
    background: #9FF;
    color: #000;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    width: 180px;
}
```

[**My New Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lx8Ca/1/)

Comment: That'll still be relative to the window, unless he sets its parent to `relative`.

Comment: @Mr.Alien I did what you said. It Kind of Worked. But, with this, the footer is no longer being shown stuck to the bottom of the browser. 

But, it is correctly placed at the bottom-right of the #maincontainer.

Comment: wrap the thing you want to move towards right using a div, not the entire footer div..btw if it's not at the bottom than where is it?

Comment: Wrapping Did not Help, Here is the http://jsfiddle.net/Lx8Ca/. I will be greatful if you check and help.

Comment: @RohitSmith you should mark the answer as correct so that fellow users can refer

Answer (score 0):

Add `position: relative` to the container, and then use the `right` property.

So your full CSS would look something like this:

```
#main,
#maincontent {
    position: relative;
}

footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 50px;
    height: 35px;
    margin: 0px 50px 0px 0px;
    background: #9FF;
    color: #000;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 10px 30px;
}
```

Comment: The Element get positined to the right. But the footer starts showing up at the top of the #maincontent.

Comment: Please post your HTML and CSS into a jsFiddle.

Comment: I thought your `footer` was supposed to be inside `#main` or `#maincontent`? In your fiddle, it's in `body`

Answer (score 0):

Remove `float` and give `right:50px` (or your desired value) to it. if it still doesnt work then give `clear:both;`and also check your `padding` and `margin` values.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a centralized container to the footer with the same with that #main or #maincontent. And then use the margin inside that footer container.